# Prove that if a function respects the Cauchy Riemann condition and it is invertible, it is conformal.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, holomorphic-functions

I need to prove that if a function respects the Cauchy Riemann condition and it is invertible, it is conformal.

I'm familiar with the proof that if a function is holomorphic and has non vanishing derivate then it's a conformal mapping. 
But i don't really know how to proof this one.

Comment: **Hint** What can you say about the Jacobian of the map?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting only in the title.

Comment: @Travis well in order to be a conformal the derivate must be non zero, so i suppose the determinant of the jacobian must be different from zero?

Answer (score 0):

If a holomorphic function is one-to-one then the derivative never vanishes. Ref. See the theorem just before Global Cuachy's Theorem in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.